# adding an element to a json array in php

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have an array of json data :

```
Array
(
    [statuses] => Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [metadata] => Array
            (
                [result_type] => recent
                [iso_language_code] => en
            )

        [created_at] => Sun Feb 23 21:50:00 +0000 2014
        [id] => 4.3770592875932E+17
        [id_str] => 437705928759320577
        [text] => 2 new iPhone leads have just broken within 5 minutes of each. What are the odds of that?! No phone for a few days then!!!!
        [source] => Twitter for iPad
        [truncated] => 
        [in_reply_to_status_id] => 
        [in_reply_to_status_id_str] => 
        [in_reply_to_user_id] => 
        [in_reply_to_user_id_str] => 
        [in_reply_to_screen_name] => 
        [user] => Array
            (
                [id] => 221418717
                [id_str] => 221418717
                [name] => Craig Price
                [screen_name] => CraigPrice1
                [location] => Glanamman
                [description] => Beer & Sport!
                [url] => 
                [entities] => Array
                    (
                        [description] => Array
                            (
                                [urls] => Array
                                    (
                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [protected] => 
                [followers_count] => 269
                [friends_count] => 765
                [listed_count] => 1
                [created_at] => Tue Nov 30 16:28:40 +0000 2010
                [favourites_count] => 520
                [utc_offset] => 0
                [time_zone] => London
                [geo_enabled] => 1
                [verified] => 
                [statuses_count] => 2852
                [lang] => en
                [contributors_enabled] => 
                [is_translator] => 
                [is_translation_enabled] => 
                [profile_background_color] => 0F0F0F
                [profile_background_image_url] => http://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme15/bg.png
                [profile_background_image_url_https] => https://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme15/bg.png
                [profile_background_tile] => 1
                [profile_image_url] => http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/435485486153756672/cSzrw5eX_normal.jpeg
                [profile_image_url_https] => https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/435485486153756672/cSzrw5eX_normal.jpeg
                [profile_banner_url] => https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/221418717/1392662771
                [profile_link_color] => FA0000
                [profile_sidebar_border_color] => EB0000
                [profile_sidebar_fill_color] => C0DFEC
                [profile_text_color] => 333333
                [profile_use_background_image] => 1
                [default_profile] => 
                [default_profile_image] => 
                [following] => 
                [follow_request_sent] => 
                [notifications] => 
            )

        [geo] => 
        [coordinates] => 
        [place] => 
        [contributors] => 
        [retweet_count] => 0
        [favorite_count] => 0
        [entities] => Array
            (
                [hashtags] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [symbols] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [urls] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [user_mentions] => Array
                    (
                    )

            )

        [favorited] => 
        [retweeted] => 
        [lang] => en
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [metadata] => Array
            (
                [result_type] => recent
                [iso_language_code] => en
            )

        [created_at] => Sun Feb 23 21:26:01 +0000 2014
        [id] => 4.3769989372629E+17
        [id_str] => 437699893726289920
        [text] => @Mogz1457 how about a broken IPhone 3 eh?
        [source] => Twitter for iPhone
        [truncated] => 
        [in_reply_to_status_id] => 4.3757491419192E+17
        [in_reply_to_status_id_str] => 437574914191917056
        [in_reply_to_user_id] => 347149526
        [in_reply_to_user_id_str] => 347149526
        [in_reply_to_screen_name] => Mogz1457
        [user] => Array
            (
                [id] => 2353482857
                [id_str] => 2353482857
                [name] => Gwilym McCann
                [screen_name] => theBigg_Mac
                [location] => Cymru/Wales
                [description] => The original Big Mac
                [url] => 
                [entities] => Array
                    (
                        [description] => Array
                            (
                                [urls] => Array
                                    (
                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [protected] => 
                [followers_count] => 5
                [friends_count] => 6
                [listed_count] => 0
                [created_at] => Wed Feb 19 23:31:15 +0000 2014
                [favourites_count] => 1
                [utc_offset] => 
                [time_zone] => 
                [geo_enabled] => 
                [verified] => 
                [statuses_count] => 3
                [lang] => en
                [contributors_enabled] => 
                [is_translator] => 
                [is_translation_enabled] => 
                [profile_background_color] => C0DEED
                [profile_background_image_url] => http://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png
                [profile_background_image_url_https] => https://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png
                [profile_background_tile] => 
                [profile_image_url] => http://abs.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_5_normal.png
                [profile_image_url_https] => https://abs.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_5_normal.png
                [profile_banner_url] => https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/2353482857/1392853158
                [profile_link_color] => 0084B4
                [profile_sidebar_border_color] => C0DEED
                [profile_sidebar_fill_color] => DDEEF6
                [profile_text_color] => 333333
                [profile_use_background_image] => 1
                [default_profile] => 1
                [default_profile_image] => 1
                [following] => 
                [follow_request_sent] => 
                [notifications] => 
            )

        [geo] => 
        [coordinates] => 
        [place] => 
        [contributors] => 
        [retweet_count] => 0
        [favorite_count] => 0
        [entities] => Array
            (
                [hashtags] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [symbols] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [urls] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [user_mentions] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [screen_name] => Mogz1457
                                [name] => Morgan Williams
                                [id] => 347149526
                                [id_str] => 347149526
                                [indices] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => 0
                                        [1] => 9
                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

        [favorited] => 
        [retweeted] => 
        [lang] => en
    )
```

I would like to add an attribute to each element in the array in the user element so it would end up like this

```
[user] => Array
        (
            [id] => 221418717
            [id_str] => 221418717
            [name] => Craig Price
            [screen_name] => CraigPrice1
            [location] => Glanamman
            [description] => Beer & Sport!
            [url] => 
            [entities] => Array
            ***[selected] => 0***
                (
                    [description] => Array
                        (
                            [urls] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                )
```

How would i go about doing this. This is what I came up with but to no avail:

```
$list = file_get_contents('tweets.json');

$json = json_decode($list, true);

    foreach($json as $key => $val)
{
   $array[$key]['selected'] = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `$json` instead of `$array` :

```
$json[$key]['selected'] = 0;
```